# Incorrect data comes out when applying OrderBy to an int member of a model property?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting to implement a sorting mechanism in one of my views, but it looks like `OrderBy` can't handle "big" (more below) integer fields, ending up in a messed up order.

Here is all the code involved, stripped down as much as possible:

**Models:**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyOption Option { get; set; }
}
public class MyOption
{
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public string Descr{get; set;}
}
```

**DisplayTemplates\MyOption**

```
@model MyOption
@Html.Label(Model.Description)
```

**Controller's returning view:**

```
@model List<MyModel>
<ul>
@foreach(var row in Model)
{
    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(x => row.Option)</li>
}
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
private List<MyModel> FakeRetrieveFromRepo()
{
    return new List<MyModel>
    {
        new MyModel { Option = new MyOption { Value = 121370002, Descr = "One" }},
        new MyModel { Option = new MyOption { Value = 121370000, Descr = "Two" }},
        new MyModel { Option = new MyOption { Value = 121370001, Descr = "Three" }},
    };

    // Debugging confirms this order is kept
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MyModel> data = FakeRetrieveFromRepo();

    // "Offending" line: sorting is supposed to be done here
    // neither .Option nor .Option.Value can be null
    data = data.OrderBy(row => row.Option.Value).ToList();

    // I expect the list to be sorted in this fashion
    //  [ {Option={ Value = 121370000, Descr = "Two" }},
    //    {Option={ Value = 121370001, Descr = "Three" }},
    //    {Option={ Value = 121370002, Descr = "One" }} ]

    return View(data);
}
```

If I try and sort like this, *no sorting actually takes place*, data in the view is in the same order in which it was provided by the repository. If I change that line like this, magically the sorting happens and gives me the expected result:

```
    // If I change the line like this, sorting takes place!
    data = data.OrderBy(row => row.Option.Value % 121370000).ToList();
```

I'm well used to implementing obscure workarounds to make stuff work, but it looks like there's something I don't know here: it seems like `OrderBy` only handles small numbers correctly ?

Comment: Your order `121370002, 121370000,121370001` doesn't match either ascending **or** descending order for numbers.

Comment: That's because that's the unsorted list....?

Comment: can you explain the controller code in `Index()`? you create a new empty list; you then create a sorted projection from that empty list, and throw the projection into a new list... and then claim it is "OFFENDING". In what way is an empty list offending?

Comment: I'd imagine since this is a cut down codebase there is some missing code (or a typo) - otherwise that sounds like a fair argument Marc :)

Comment: @Charleh my point is: it is impossible for us to point out the error in code that doesn't actually show the problem. I suspect this inquiry is critical to spotting the error here...

Comment: Does `row.Option` always have a value? If you've got a null value in there that might break the sort somehow.

Comment: @Charleh also, re your other comment - that order (...2, ...0, ...1) is what the OP states they want it to look like *when sorted*. So: we have a bizarre intended output, based on zero input. That makes it really hard to answer.

Comment: Data comes from a repository, I stripped down *too much*. I also fixed various things that I missed and added more info.

Comment: @Alex it is still stripped too much; look carefully - you have a list of `MyModel`, and seem to be sorting on `row.Option.Value` - but `row.Option` is a `List<MyOption>` - thus `.Value` **does not exist**. Equally, the view takes a `MyModel`, but you're feeding it a `List<MyModel>`. The fake repo uses properties on `MyModel` *that do not exist* (they are on `MyOption`). Then the view does a `foreach` on `Model`, noting that `Model` is **not** enumerable in any way. I think we'll be happy to help, but your question isn't making that possible.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for pointing that out: that's a (now fixed) typo.

Comment: @MarcGravell not sure if you read it right then - in the original revision: `Assume that the values which need to be sorted look like this: 121370002, 121370000, 121370001` - which implies that the items in that list haven't been sorted (they *need* to be sorted). I didn't see an example of how a sorted list should look in the originally posted question

Comment: @Alex the `FakeRetrieveFromRepo` code still can't compile...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've reduced the code in the question to the following - and it works absolutely fine; .NET can work perfectly well with large numbers. So that leaves us with the most likely answer that the problem **is not in the example** - simplifying code is great, but you need to find a minimal *runnable* example that **shows the problem**. Most times, when trying to get a minimal repro, the very act of finding "what is different between my example code, and my real code" will tell you what the problem *is*. Unfortunately, we can't do that for you, because we can't see the real code.

The following works fine:

```
static void Main()
{
    var data = FakeRetrieveFromRepo();
    // order here is "One", "Two", "Three"
    data = data.OrderBy(row => row.Option.Value).ToList();
    // order here is "Two", "Three", "One"
}
private static List<MyModel> FakeRetrieveFromRepo()
{
    return new List<MyModel>
    {
        new MyModel { Option = new MyOption {
           Value = 121370002, Description = "One" }},
        new MyModel { Option = new MyOption {
           Value = 121370000, Description = "Two" }},
        new MyModel { Option = new MyOption {
           Value = 121370001, Description = "Three" }},
    };
}
```

Purely as an aside, assuming you don't need to leave the original list alone (caching, etc) - an in-place sort is more efficient:

```
data.Sort((x, y) => x.Option.Value.CompareTo(y.Option.Value));
```

Comment: @Alex if it did, then I strongly suspect the original code was `data.OrderBy(x => x.Option.Value).ToList();`, rather than `data = data.OrderBy(x => x.Option.Value).ToList();` - the first of these ***does exactly nothing useful***. The second creates a sorted projection as a list. Well, actually they *both* do that, but the first one does all the hard work and then throws the answer away - the second goes the extra mile by storing a reference to the newly sorted copy of the data.